# Maximam r distance for Ripley's K-function

Tags: r, clustering, spatial, point-process

I am using R's [package spatstat](http://www.spatstat.org/spatstat/) to study the locational pattern of conflict events in Africa (around 8.000 points) using point pattern analysis techniques.

I was able to obtain the plot of $g(r)$, the pair correlation function, using the contour of the African continent as my study region. The size of the enclosing rectangle is around 8.546km by 10.423km.

Spatstat does a nice job and gives me the plot of $g(r)$, but I noticed that the computation is not performed for $r > 625km$.
Looking at [this reply](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-Ripley-s-K-function-within-envelope-how-to-change-the-maximum-distance-td852433.html) and in the function's source code, I understood that spatstat uses a rule of thumb stating that the biggest $r$ for which to compute Ripley's K-function and its variations should not excede 25% of the shortest side of the rectangle enclosing the study region.

**My questions are thus the following:**

1. Is this rule of thumb also valid for complex polygons as it is for rectangles?
2. What happens to my K-function if I compute it for a larger $r$ than what is advised?
3. Is there any literature addressing this specific problem (size of $r$, polygonal windows)?

Comment: Could you make the dataset available so it is possible to have a closer look at the problem?

Comment: Regarding point 2: You simply get an estimate with a very large variance, so the true K-function for the underlying random phenomenon may be quite far from what you see in the estimate.